# Router returns error but works just fine when I compile the app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <>
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route errorElement={<ErrorView />} path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                <Route path="/stacks" element={<StackList />} />
                <Route path="/stacks/:name" element={<StackDetails />} />
                <Route path="/instances" element={<InstancesList />} />
                <Route path="/new" element={<NewInstance />} />
            </Route>
        </>
    )
)
```

But when I run "yarn start" I get the following error

```
ERROR in src/index.tsx:18:5
TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").RouteObject[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").RouteObject[]'.
  Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").RouteObject' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").RouteObject'.
    Type 'IndexRouteObject' is not assignable to type 'RouteObject'.
      Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").IndexRouteObject' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/context").IndexRouteObject'.
        Types of property 'shouldRevalidate' are incompatible.
          Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").ShouldRevalidateFunction' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").ShouldRevalidateFunction'.
            Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
              Type '{ currentUrl: URL; currentParams: import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").Params<string>; nextUrl: URL; nextParams: import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").Params<...>; ... 5 more ...; defaultShouldRevalidate: boolean...' is not assignable to type '{ currentUrl: URL; currentParams: import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").Params<string>; ... 7 more ...; defaultShouldRevalidate: boolean; }'.
                Types of property 'actionResult' are incompatible.
                  Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DataResult' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DataResult'.
                    Type 'DeferredResult' is not assignable to type 'DataResult'.
                      Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DeferredResult' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DeferredResult'.
                        Types of property 'deferredData' are incompatible.
                          Type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DeferredData' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/tons/IdeaProjects/im-web-client/node_modules/react-router/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils").DeferredData'.
                            Types have separate declarations of a private property 'pendingKeys'.
    16 |
    17 | const router = createBrowserRouter(
  > 18 |     createRoutesFromElements(
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 19 |         <>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 20 |             <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 21 |             <Route errorElement={<ErrorView />} path="/" element={<Layout />}>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 22 |                 <Route path="/stacks" element={<StackList />} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 23 |                 <Route path="/stacks/:name" element={<StackDetails />} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 24 |                 <Route path="/instances" element={<InstancesList />} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 25 |                 <Route path="/new" element={<NewInstance />} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 26 |             </Route>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 27 |         </>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 28 |     )
       | ^^^^^^
    29 | )
    30 |
    31 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
```

Anyone here who got an idea about what's wrong?

UPDATE - include package.json

```
{
    "name": "instance-manager",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@dhis2/app-runtime": "^3.6.1",
        "@dhis2/d2-i18n": "^1.1.0",
        "@dhis2/ui": "^8.6.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "axios": "^1.1.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-auth-kit": "^2.6.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router": "^6.4.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "styled-jsx": "^5.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "format": "yarn d2-style apply"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@dhis2/cli-style": "^10.4.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your start script look like? Are you saying starting the app and running a local development build had issues, but that if you actually build it it runs without issue? Can you share your build script and how you are running/serving the app then that doesn't have the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I've add my packages.json to the post. Please let me know if there's anything else I should post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed versions of some dependencies. `react-router-dom@6` is complete written in Typescript, so there's no need to include `@types/react-router-dom` as a dependency, especially since it's the RRDv5 type bindings. I suspect this is messing with the development builds.

To uninstall the old dependency that is no longer required, run:

```
npm uninstall --save @types/react-router-dom
```

`react-router-dom` also re-exports everything from `react-router` that I'm aware of, so you don't necessarily need that dependency either, remove it with:

```
npm un -s react-router
```

or at a minimum if you have both you should ensure they are on the same version:

```
npm i -s react-router@6 react-router-dom@6
```

This will install the latest v6 version for both. OFC you can always be more specific with the versioning if you need.